# Проблема со знаками на странице участника

Tags: дефект, дизайн, знаки, страница-учётной-записи, тёмная-тема

На странице участника знаки отображаются в чёрных прямоугольниках. Собственно, вот в темной теме:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
В белой теме такое происходит при наведении курсора на знак.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/404462/3240681

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359630/383809 тоже, но с другой стороны.